# What does a 10nm/20nm circle on instrument approach charts mean?

Tags: approach, aeronautical-charts, ifr-navigation

[image: ILS instrument approach chart]

A lot of instrument aproach charts (VOR or ILS) have a circle around the navaid. It can be 10/20 NM or in km, like the 20km circle in the image. What does this circle mean?

Comment: You may want to ask what it's used for rather than what it means, as I think you know it shows the distance that is 10 NM from the centre.

Comment: Yeap. Because, as I understood from the answer below (as Annex 4 says), it shows only radial scale. I thought, it has some additional function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be 20 km, **or** 10 NM.

Since you've shown an ICAO-style plate, ICAO [Annex 4 Aeronautical Charts](https://www.casa.gov.au/sites/g/files/net351/f/_assets/main/lib91135/an04_cons.pdf) says:

> 11.3.3.1 Except where this is not practicable, a distance
>   circle with a radius of 20 km (10 NM) centred on a DME
>   located on or close to the aerodrome, or on the aerodrome
>   reference point where no suitable DME is available, shall be
>   shown; its radius shall be indicated on the circumference.

So whenever possible, this circle must be shown.

Comment: But why is it required? To quickly estimate the relative distance?

Answer (score 4):

https://www.flightliteracy.com/instrument-approach-procedure-charts-part-two/

Normally, approach features within the plan view are shown to scale; however, only the data within the reference circle is always drawn to scale.

Comment: Wow, after 3 years!   Congrats.  Not sure that this is the fundamental *reason* for the reference circle, but-- definitely a good insight there,